# Is there a good javascript WYSIWYG tool that uses absolute positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, wysiwyg, css-position

I'm building a site where users (with no knowledge of html/css) will custom-design simple static HTML pages.  Years ago, I used a CMS that used absolute positioning with drag and drop for designing static pages, and it was a fantastically easy UI for anyone to grasp.

I'm wondering if there's a javascript solution for this that I could implement in my new site.  It would need the basic bold, italic, font size, image uploads available in something like TinyMCE, but I'd also like for elements to be positioned absolutely by the user.

Anyone know of such a solution?

JQuery solutions are fine, since I'm using JQuery anyway on the site.  I'd prefer not to have to load in a second framework.

Comment: So, have you open sourced this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no specific solutions. I wonder if you implement a jquery drag and drop plugin, on the drop you could get the dropped coordinates and dynamically create a CSS file for the dropped element containing those absolute coordinates.

Comment: That sounds like a plan.  If I end up building this thing I'll open source it so there can be a real answer to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [YAML Builder](http://builder.yaml.de/) (for inspiration). It's not exactly what you're searching for but it is a WYSIWYG website editor relying heavily on jQuery and jQuery UI. Although, it's built for developers and not for noobs.